# How to find a smallest parallelepiped that bounds the unit ball in a normed space

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

Consider a finite dimensional normed space $(V,\Vert \cdot \Vert)$. How to find a basis $(e_i)$ of $V$ such that the unit closed ball $\overline B_1$ centered at $0$ is contained in $ P:= \{ x \in V : \vert x_i \vert \leq 1 \} $ and $P$ is minimal with regard to the Hausdorff measure. Is it possible to find $e_i$ such that $\Vert e_i-e_j \Vert < 2$ for all $i,j$?

Comment: The $n$-dimensional Hausdorff measure $\mathcal H^n$ associated with $\|\cdot\|$ is a multiple of the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure $\mathcal L^n$, since it is a Borel measure, finite on bounded sets, and translation invariant. So in the statement one can equivalently  use $\mathcal L^n$ instead of $\mathcal H^n$.

Comment: Let $(E_i)_{1\le i\le n}$ denote the standard basis of $\mathbb R^n$ and $L$ the change of basis matrix, $Le_i=E_i$. We can then rephrase the optimisation problem as: maximise $|\det L|$ among all $n\times n$ matrices $L$ with $\|L\|\le1$, where $\|L\|$ is the operator norm of $L:(\mathbb R^n,\|\cdot\|)\to (\mathbb R^n,\|\cdot\|_\infty)$.